# How to decide between standardized mean difference (SMD) and log2fold change (log2FC) before doing meta-analysis?

Tags: statistics, meta-analysis

I want to do **meta-analysis of alpha diversity** between test and control groups across 10 different populations. I want to see what is the summed effect (pool effect) of intervention between the two groups for alpha diversity. For that, first I need the intervention effect on test group's alpha diversity for individual population dataset. How should I calculate this? Should I calculate this by difference in the log transformed mean values of the groups (**log2FC**) or should I calculate **SMD** for each study?
Thanks

Comment: Cross-posted on biostars: https://www.biostars.org/p/9468060/

Comment: what is the measure of alpha-diversity? counts or proportion?